# Automatic repair couldn’t repair PC: looking for ntfs.sys on wrong drive

Tags: windows-10, boot, repair

On boot, my 3-4 months old Windows 10 EDU / NUC7 PC showed a "blue screen":
"Windows 10 Automatic repair couldn't repair your PC"

[image]

I shut down the system and instantly rebooted.
This time the PC started normal and showed the lock screen after 5+ seconds (my system is pretty fast, thanks to an EVO 960 SSD. But I do not use over provisioning or anything else special).

I inspected the mentioned log file in "C:/windows/system32/logfiles/srt/srttrail.txt"
and found this error message:

> Root cause found:
>    Boot critical file d:\windows\system32\drivers\ntfs.sys is corrupt.
>   Repair action: File repair
>   Result: Failed. Error code =  0x490 Time
>   taken = 2313 ms

The strange thing is, there is **no** Windows installation on the D drive. So, no wonder it couldn't find the NTFS driver there.

The system seems back to normal. But what should I do now? Do I need to worry or was this just another strange Windows 10 hickup?

Comment: Looks like the drive mounted as the wrong letter. Did you have some other drive plugged in - USB or otherwise? Have you made any changes to the BIOS settings?

Comment: Let me think; I have detached an external USB DVD drive on one of the last boots (but not the last one). And I noticed Samsung Magician showed up for no apparent reason on my last good login. Other than that, no changes whatsoever.

Comment: Three months later now, this has never happened again. So, just a hickup.